# SelectedValue in DropDownList unable to select any value (VB.Net, Asp.Net)

Tags: vb.net, webforms, selectedvalue

I have a DropDownList inside my form and I added those list using code behind like this :

```
With DropDownList1
    .Items.Clear()
    .Items.Add(New ListItem(" --- None --- ", ""))
    .Items.Add(New ListItem("01", "1"))
    .Items.Add(New ListItem("02", "2"))
End With
```

So here are my coding that doing the action when value inside the DropDownList is selected :

```
If Not DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "" Then
    If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "1" Then
        ' Some statement goes here
    ElseIf DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "2" Then
        ' Some statement goes here
    End If
End If
```

So the problem here is, when I run my web and select value from list, it select nothing. The result is always `DropDownList1.SelectedValue = ""`. I wonder why. Somebody guide me please. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you place your first code snippets? Inside the Page Load event?

Comment: Yes I put it inside the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your *DropDownList* is initialized every time when your form loads (*I assume that you placed the population in form load*) or do a ***PostBack***, thus resetting the value of the *DropDownList* to *""*. Try covering the *DropDownList* population in a ***IsPostBack*** condition. Like this:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
     With DropDownList1
         .Items.Clear()
         .Items.Add(New ListItem(" --- None --- ", ""))
         .Items.Add(New ListItem("01", "1"))
         .Items.Add(New ListItem("02", "2"))
     End With
End If
```

Comment: You are right! This is actually the way to do it. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it helped you. :)